# how to compare a class attribute with another attribute value in the same instance on creation and changing time inside the class

Tags: python, class, attributes, compare, self

In a timeperiod the starting point has to be smaller than the endpoint. (2000 < 2020)

My goal is a python class that compares these two values on creation time or whenever one is changed to test if they are plausible. But this should take place **inside** the class.

I tried someting like this in different variations - with no success:

```
class Timeperiod:
    def __init__(self, start, end):
        self._start = start
        self._end = end

    @property
    def start(self):
        return self._start
    @start.setter
    def start(self, start):
        # if start > self._end: ### <- How to reach the 'self._end' value from here?
        #     print ('ERROR')   ### <- to throw an error.
        self._start = start

    @property
    def end(self):
        return self._end
    @end.setter
    def end(self, end):
        # if end < self._start:
        #     print ('ERROR')
        self._end = end

tp = Timeperiod(2000, 2020)
print (tp.start, '<', tp.end,': ',tp.start < tp.end) ### <- Test outside the class
tp.start = 2050
print (tp.start, '<', tp.end,': ',tp.start < tp.end)
```

I can easily test the values outside the class, but how to compare them **inside** the class?

As far as I've learned, methods like ´__gt__´ compares values of different instances, for me they seem not to be suitable in this case. I've focused myself on the setter-method but with all my attempts I got nearly every possible attribute error.

Where's the key?

Comment: I just copied and pasted the code and it executed fine, even after uncommenting `if start > self._end: ### <- How to reach the 'self._end' value from here?
            print ('ERROR')   ### <- to throw an error.`. What is the error you get? What do you expect to happen? Should it check the values on creating the object?

Comment: Unfortunately, you are right :-( I also copied and pasted the code I posted. But then I simplified it and made some changes for better understanding. Obviously I accidentally ran it like this. Before, I got various attribute errors "Has no attribute, has too much, has too little, has something else ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what your problem is. `self._end` is exactly how you access the end point from inside the `start` setter. Rather than just print an error message, though, you should raise an exception if setting a value would break the invariant `self._start = self._end`.

However, if the problem you are having is ensuring that `start < end` is true inside `__init__` as well, I would define a private method for verifying this invariant. It can then be used in `__init__` as well as in both setters.

```
class Timeperiod:
    def __init__(self, start, end):
        self._assert_valid_range(start, end)
        self.start = start
        self.end = end

    @staticmethod
    def _assert_valid_range(start, end):
        if start >= end:
            raise ValueError(f"Attempt to use start ({start}) >= end ({end})")

    @property
    def start(self):
        return self._start

    @start.setter
    def start(self, start):
        self._assert_valid_range(start, self._end)
        self._start = start

    @property
    def end(self):
        return self._end

    @end.setter
    def end(self, end):
        self._assert_valid_range(self._start, end)
        self._end = end
```

Comment: Your idea with the staticmethod does the job! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Solution: you're probably using python 2.7. In run your code in that version of python, and it happened the same as you say.

But when running the same script with python 3.7, it work just fine. So, the solution is simple:

Upgrade your python interpreter. Python 2 is no longer manteined anyway.

Hope I could help

Comment: Well, you could use a new style class in python 2